# static types cannot be used as parameters in htmlhelpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created custom HtmlHelper like this:

```
public static class HtmlHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CreateHr(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("<div class='line'></div>");
    }
}
```

but when I build project I get this Error:

> static types cannot be used as parameters

I searched Google, but I can't find similar question.
How can I do this?

Comment: Call your class something other than `HtmlHelper`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call your class something other than `HtmlHelper`, like `HtmlHelperExtensions`.

Not only are you not allowed to have a static class as a method parameter type (because it would make no sense), you would be shadowing the very class you're trying to extend.

Answer (score 0):

Do not name your helper `HtmlHelper` because this means you try to shadow base HtmlHelper from MVC framework. Instead try:

```cs
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Helpers
{
     public static class HrExtensions
     {
          public static string CreateHr(this HtmlHelper helper)
          {
               return MvcHtmlString.Create("<div class='line'></div>");
          }
     }
}
```

more details here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs